# Dynamic aspects of Rails 4 app not working in production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I just deployed my first rails 4 app to a VPS and now I cannot write to the production database. Everything deployed fine (migrations etc) and I can log on the mysql database with sequel pro and see it is all there however when I try create a user using the app's new user form instead of notifying 'Thank you for registering' (as it does in development) it asks me to login to proceed. No record is created in the database.

I can see in the log that it is binding show rather than the users id to the :id parameter and therefore redirecting to login rather than creating a session. Why would this be?

This is the app log

```
I, [2014-08-09T00:33:45.753714 #31030]  INFO -- : Started GET "/login" for xx.xxx.xxx.xx at 2014-08-09 00:33:45 +0200
I, [2014-08-09T00:33:45.755372 #31030]  INFO -- : Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
I, [2014-08-09T00:33:45.757942 #31030]  INFO -- :   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
I, [2014-08-09T00:33:45.758940 #31030]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
I, [2014-08-09T00:33:52.048559 #31030]  INFO -- : Started POST "/sessions" for xx.xxx.xxx.xx at 2014-08-09 00:33:52 +0200
I, [2014-08-09T00:33:52.050765 #31030]  INFO -- : Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2014-08-09T00:33:52.050912 #31030]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?^?^?", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "email"=>"xxxx@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log In"}
I, [2014-08-09T00:33:52.056027 #31030]  INFO -- :   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
I, [2014-08-09T00:33:52.057333 #31030]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 3.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
I, [2014-08-09T00:34:16.625949 #31030]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/show" for 92.225.136.50 at 2014-08-09 00:34:16 +0200
I, [2014-08-09T00:34:16.628217 #31030]  INFO -- : Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
I, [2014-08-09T00:34:16.628359 #31030]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"show"}
I, [2014-08-09T00:34:16.630009 #31030]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/
I, [2014-08-09T00:34:16.630207 #31030]  INFO -- : Filter chain halted as :authorize rendered or redirected
I, [2014-08-09T00:34:16.630443 #31030]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Edit 1: Here is my session controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to users_path, notice: "Logged In!"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Email or password is invalid. Please try again."
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged Out!"
  end
end
```

And here is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize, except: [:new]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
   end

   def update
     respond_to do |format|
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.present?
    @user.destroy
    end
    redirect_to users_path, notice: "User successfully deleted."
   end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user].permit(:name, :surname, :title, :telefon, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :salt, :encrypted_password))
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Vielen Dank für Ihre Anmeldung"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  private
  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :title, :telefon, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :salt, :encrypted_password)
  end
end
```

Comment: Seeing some code would help

Comment: I added my seesions and users controllers. Anything else I should add?

Comment: Have you compared the output of `rake routes` on your development box vs the production box?

Comment: Rake routes output is exactly the same on both

Comment: Ok so I figured out where the problem lies. The app checks the authorize settings in the users_controller.rb before creating the session which in turn stops the session being created. This behaviour is not happening on my development box. Could anyone give some insight  into why this is happening please?

Comment: Also is it safe to exclude the user create action from being authorized or will this leave a security vulnerability in the app?